# Parsing an HTML file through Emacs Lisp

Tags: html, parsing, elisp

I need to parse an HTML file in order to store all the fields of a table in a list through Emacs Lisp.
Although a function like libxml-parse-html-region could do that work for me, Emacs should have been compiled with libxml2 support in advance and as I do not have admin privileges on this machine I cannot use that function.
Therefore, can you share some other options with me in order to get the job accomplished taking into account the referred constraints  ?

Answer (score 1):

You can found various [XML Parser](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/XmlParser) on EmacsWiki

Answer (score 1):

You could build your own Emacs just for your user?